# JavaScript - Object creation vs update

Tags: javascript, performance, object

In JavaScript:

Example 1:

`var x = {};`
`x.a = 10;`

Example 2:

`var x = {};`
`x = {a: 10};`

Is there any difference between Example 1 & 2 on the basis of performance, considering that a lot of properties need to be attached to `var x`, and not just `a`.

Which is more efficient?

Comment: `x = {a: 10};` replaces the old object that `x` was pointing to with `{a: 10}`. There is no point to initializing `x` to equal `{}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go for option 3:

```
var x = {
    a: 10,
    b: 20,
    // etc
};
```

Don't declare `x` as a empty object, only to replace it with an object with an `a` property.

When you need to set a large amount of properties on a object, using a object literal like that is more efficient than adding every single property separately. However, the difference will be negligible.

The disadvantage of option #1 is:
1 operation for every single property to add to the object, which will have an effect when larger amounts of properties are required.

The disadvantage of option #2 is:
You're declaring the object, then *replacing* it completely.

My suggestion simply adds all required properties to the object in one go, without replacing the variable.

Comment: There wasn't option 3 in question.

Comment: @Vladimirs: so? What I'm saying is that neither of the options the OP posted are a very good idea. I'm suggesting an alternative to those 2 options.

Comment: So that is not an answer to the question.. And author is not looking for alternatives but just wants to find out which one is efficient (based on his question)

Comment: @Vladimirs OP wants the most efficient way. Just because he wasn't aware of this option doesn't mean it's not an answer.

Comment: @SecondRikudo where it says that OP wants the most efficient way? He provided two examples and want to know what the difference is between then.

Comment: @Cerbrus Option 3 does not hold when you have to add properties on the go. But your rest of the answer explains something.

Comment: @G.D.Singh: True, but in that case, you can add whatever properties you have in advance, the way I suggested. Whatever you have to add later, can only really be added like you do in option 1.

Comment: You don't have understanding of what question is about. example might be simplified to not give whole details of usage which might be a key thing.

Comment: @Vladimirs How do I pin a nail to my wall? With a spoon or with a fork? By your logic, you'd say the spoon, I'd say it's the hammer.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400235/javascript-object-creation-vs-update/27400295#comment43246314_27400295) is a good example of how not to ask a question on SO.

Comment: [Just a small performance test to prove my point.](http://jsperf.com/object-declaration-separate-literal-replace-literal)

Comment: @Cerbrus That's correct. I ran some tests myself, and conclusion is Example 1 is faster.

Comment: @G.D.Singh: True, but only when you're setting a small amount of properties. If you take a look at the jsperf I posted, You'll see that for multiple properties, a single object literal is faster.